Install bitstruct in python msys2
I am using msys2 (latest version from today 2024-05-30), it embeds python 3.11. I have a project requiring "bitstruct" through "pip3 install bitstruct". It tries to get it in the version 8.19.0.
When trying to build it, it ends up with the following error, I tried to follow some forums stuff but without success:
 pip3 install bitstruct
Collecting bitstruct
  Using cached bitstruct-8.19.0.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: bitstruct
  Building wheel for bitstruct (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for bitstruct (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311/bitstruct
      copying src/bitstruct/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311/bitstruct
      running egg_info
      writing src/bitstruct.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/bitstruct.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src/bitstruct.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/bitstruct.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src/bitstruct.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/bitstruct/bitstream.c -> build/lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311/bitstruct
      copying src/bitstruct/bitstream.h -> build/lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311/bitstruct
      copying src/bitstruct/c.c -> build/lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311/bitstruct
      running build_ext
      building 'bitstruct.c' extension
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bitstruct
Failed to build bitstruct
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bitstruct, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Not familiar with msys2 but I'm guessing it gives you a windows environment to work with on a non-windows platform. If so, then perhaps you need pip install bitstruct  instead of pip3 install bitstruct

It fails with complaining with:
 C:/msys64/usr/include/python3.11/pyport.h:236:10: fatal error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory
        236 | #include <sys/select.h>


I just encountered a similar issue, and I came here to find a solution. Additionally, mine mentioned:

error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed: No such file or directory.

This was able to be fixed by doing:
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu

within linux. Additional possible solutions to your issue might be:
sudo apt-get install pythonXX-dev

where xx == version.
